# WPF: ComboBox ItemTemplate doesn't get applied until I select the box

Tags: wpf, combobox, itemtemplate

I have a ViewModel with a property that is a instance of a class. When I edit said ViewModel I have a ComboBox dynamically bound to a collection of the class. Problem is that if the Item has the instance before editing the ItemTemplate won't get applied until I select and expand the ComboBox.

So when I pop up the Edit window the item appearing in the comboBox is `myProject.myNameSpace.Type` but as soon as I click the ComboBox it turns into `NameOfType SomeInfo` like it should be.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
      Width="Auto"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Type, Mode=TwoWay}" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableTypes}"
      TextSearch.TextPath="TypeName"
      IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
      IsEditable="True" >
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Margin="4"
                       Text="{Binding Path=TypeName}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="4"
                       Text="{Binding Path=TypeInfo}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
<ComboBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                           Foreground="Red">
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</ComboBox.GroupStyle>
```

C#:

```
private ListCollectionView _availableTypes;
public ListCollectionView AvailableTypes
{
    get
    {
        if (_availableTypes == null)
        {
            _availableTypes = new ListCollectionView(Context.GetAllTypes());
            _availableTypes.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));
        }
        return _availableTypes;
    }
}

public TypeClass Type
{
    get { return Model.Type; }
    set
    {
        Model.Type = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Type");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm now pretty sure this has something to do with the IsEditable property.

Answer (score 2):

Can't reproduce. Could it be because your AvailableTypes property returns `_availableSections` instead of `_availableTypes`? If not, please post a complete, isolated repro.

Comment: No, that's a typo on my part. I can't reproduce easily as it pops up in a modal window based on a ViewModelBase that implements IEditable. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I haven't yet have time to reproduce but it is happening in few places and not in other places. Only difference seems to be that I'm binding to SelectedItem where it happens and SelectedValue where not.