# Invoke IValueConverter's ConvertBack on load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I bind combobox (that is a part if listbox item template) to enum, the selected item is bound to the collection that is bound to listbox. 
I use a converter for some logic.

The problem is that the ConvertBack is not invoked on startup, but only when I re-select the item in combobox.

I need it to invoke also on start.

```
public enum FullEnum 
    {
       Apple,
       Banana,
       Pear
    }
```

```xml
<Window.Resources>
   <local:EnumConverter x:Key="enumConverter"/>

   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="DataT"
                       MethodName="GetValues" 
                       ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="local:FullEnum" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="190*" />
       <RowDefinition Height="71*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <ListBox Name="list1" Margin="0,0,0,37">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}"></TextBlock>
               <ComboBox Height="23" Width="90"                                 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataT}}"                                                                  
                         SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Oped, Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}}">
                </ComboBox>
             </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>
  </Grid>
```

```cs
List<Item1> list = new List<Item1>();
public Window1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     list.Add(new Item1 { Label="label1" });
     list.Add(new Item1 { Label = "label2" });
     list.Add(new Item1 {  Label = "label3" });

     list1.ItemsSource = list;

}

    public class Item1
    {
            public FullEnum Oped { get; set; }
            public string Label { get; set; }
    }

 public class EnumConverterr : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //some code        
        }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((int)value != 0)
            return (EnumSuperior)value;
        return (EnumSuperior)7;
    }

    }
```

Comment: What kind of logic are you doing in convert back?

Comment: In this instance, you should be using SelectedItem, not SelectedValue (in the combo box). SelectedValue is used in the rare circumstance that you set the DisplayMemberPath and want to automatically show a child value of the selected item.

Comment: What do you see in the combobox to start with then? Your Item1 items in the list, will they get a default Enum value when constructed (can't remember how that works, if its a Int or Int? type), if not they are of course null. But I would think that the ConvertBack should still be called. Otherwise could be related to my problem (not using Converter there though) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342972/wpf-combobox-itemtemplate-doesnt-get-applied-until-i-select-the-box

Comment: @Ingó Vals, I see the first item when i start the program but the value is not sent to the object, ConvertBack is not called. only if i select some item (I can even reselect the first item, it will work)

Comment: @Josh G, it doesn't matter what i am foing in Converback, because it's not called on startup (i put break point there).

Comment: @Josh G, I must use selected value because the object has a property  public FullEnum Oped that must get/set the value selected in combobox, even if I use SelectedItem (with same binding I used for SelectedValue ), ConvertBack is not called.

Comment: @anderi: It does matter what is in ConvertBack (per my answer below) because you shouldn't NEED convert back to be called on start up.

Answer (score 0):

The return converter is not called by WPF on initialization because it has just gotten the initial values from the data context. The source and target of the data binding should have the same values so there is no reason to update the source.

You have not posted your convert back logic, but you must have some "state-ful" logic in the converter. Converters should be stateless (no side-effects, immutable). All of the conversion should be based on the value, a parameter, and converter properties that are not modified during the conversion.

If your converter is stateless, all you need to do is initialize the data source properly and you should no longer need that initial convert back call.

Comment: don;t understand, why can't I use converter to init the value? There is a problem in my logic to init the value elsewhere...

Comment: please note,there are 2 SOURCES for combobox, it loads it's data from one source and the selected value updates in another

Comment: Convert back is called when the target (in this case the ComboBox) needs to send an update back to the data source (the list of items in code behind). If the target has the same data as the source it is wasteful to update the source (and call the converter). Why would the target have a different value from the source on startup if it just got the value from the source?

Comment: So the selected value is not getting set? Is that the problem? Why do you need the call to convert back?

Comment: I've updated the post, in converter I cast the result to Another Enum that doesn't match exactly the enum that is bounded to combobox.

Comment: I have 3 types of combos, each of them has a sub set of enums, the object item has  public FullEnum Oped, a full set.

Comment: So the convert function must also convert from EnumSuperior to FullEnum, right?

Comment: @Josh G, yes. I do this there

Comment: Why not set the EnumSuperior / FullEnum value property in the constructor for Window1 when you are building the items for the list? This is where the initialization occurs.

Comment: There is a way that you can explicitly force bindings to update the source (which would call convert back). I thought about mentioning this except for two problems. First, it seems like there's an issue with how you are handling this binding. Second, because the bindings are inside of the ItemTemplates of the ListBox, it would be tricky to get a hold of the bindings to force them to update.

Comment: Object is created on run time (not as in this example), so the enum is now known. and I can't put there some dummy enum.

Comment: So the converter knows more about the data source than the initializer? You are telling me that only the converter (convert back function) can properly set up this value on the data source?!

Comment: @Josh G yes, via another control on the window user decides  which items  will be loaded into the this combobox, and the combobox updates the data source. I guess I need to change the design...